# Windows App Certification Kit fail on Badge Logo dimensions

Tags: visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

In Visual Studio 2012 (11.0.51106.01 Update 1) the .appxmanifest for my Windows Store App has the image slot for the 140% size Badge Logo listed as 34x34 (pixels).

When I run Windows App Certification Kit 2.2 against the app it fails with:

> "The image 'Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-140.png' failed the size restrictions of 33 X 33."

I resized the image to 33x33 but then Visual Studio fails with:

> > "App manifest references badge logo image 'Assets\BadgeLogo.scale-140.png' which has not valid dimensions. It must be 34x34 pixels."

Anybody else have this problem?  If so can you provide any guidance on resolving it?

Comment: Apparently it's because of VS2012 Update 1 https://twitter.com/mtaulty/status/275621093098795009

Answer (score 2):

Here is a direct link to the Microsoft workaround that you can find from the twitter link in the comments:

[You cannot use the Scale-140 badge logo in Visual Studio 2012 Update 1](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2792380)